# most important C++ container classes one should know to be a successful programmer

Tags: c++11, containers

I am trying to enhance my programming skills. Can someone help me out in letting me know the most important container classes i should be equipped with via c++ .?

Comment: You may want to refer to the [posting guidlines](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) if you're confused why you're getting downvoted...

Comment: Get yourself a [book](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/241631) and start from there instead of silly errands like trying to figure out knowing what container will make you successful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is entire page devoted to c++ containers: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/. Many of those you won't start off using however, but for beginners I would say arrays, vectors, and maps. Which container to use comes down to how you want to store the data you have.

Comment: `array` is pretty much only a performance optimisation over the dynamic allocation done by `vector`, so I'd leave it off the must-learn-first list.  `map` for sure.  `list` makes sense conceptually - different performance compromises, but it's not needed all that frequently in most problem domains I've worked in.  `unordered_map` is functionally close enough to `map` that it can be ignored initially.  So - I agree with your list except for `array`, for whatever that's worth.... O_o.